# next_permutation() in algorithm std does not seem to modify array

Tags: c++, c++11, std

I have the following program using function next_permutation() and the output:

```
 8 int main ()
 9 {
10     int myints[] = {1, 2, 3};
11
12     cout << "Before : " << myints[0] << ' ' << myints[1] << ' ' << myints[2] << endl;
13
14     do {
15         cout << "loop : ";
16         cout << myints[0] << ' ' << myints[1] << ' ' << myints[2] << endl;
17     } while ( next_permutation(myints, myints + 3) );
18
19     cout << "After : " << myints[0] << ' ' << myints[1] << ' ' << myints[2] << endl;
20
21     return 0;
22 }

$ ./a.out
Before : 1 2 3
loop : 1 2 3
loop : 1 3 2
loop : 2 1 3
loop : 2 3 1
loop : 3 1 2
loop : 3 2 1
After : 1 2 3
```

I am expecting line 19 to output "3 2 1" per the description of next_permutation() (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/next_permutation/, which has same sample program), but as can be seen the output is "1 2 3".  Can someone please help me understand.

Thank you,
Ahmed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function does precisely what the documentation that you linked says that it should do:

> If the function can determine the next higher permutation, it rearranges the elements as such and returns `true`. **If that was not possible (because it is already at the largest possible permutation), it rearranges the elements according to the first permutation (sorted in ascending order) and returns `false`.** (emphasis is added)

That is exactly what is going on: since your `do` / `while` loop has just finished, you know for sure that the call of `std::next_permutation` had returned `false`. Therefore, the array that you passed into that last call has been arranged in descending mode, making it impossible to produce the next highest permutation. That is also why you see the first permutation in the printout that follows the loop - the documentation says that when the call returns `false`, the input is sorted in ascending order.

Comment: In the original code, at line 11, the following statement was present "sort (myints, myints + 3);"   (which I deleted, and program behaved same as I expected).  I have seen similar lines in other sample programs.  Is there really a need for the sort(), since I am creating the array in ascending order?

Answer (score 0):

`next_permutation` sorts the array if it returns false, so this is the expected behavior. This is described [here on cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation).

Hope this helps!